# 406 error when I try to post a script tag on a shopify store from app

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

I am trying to post a script tag on a shopify store so that the store will show an alert once it loads. However, it gives me a 406 error and I don't know why. I am using express and I installed the shopify-node-api. The code is as follows

```js
        var des = {
   "script_tag":{
    "event":"onload",
    "display_scope":"online_store",
    "src": "http://localhost:3000/receiver.js"
   }
  };

  Shopify.post('/admin/script_tag.json', des, function(error){
   if(error){
    console.log("there was an error");
    console.log(error);
   }
   console.log("script tag imbedded");
  });
```

and this is the script I wish to embed in my store

```js
 function(){
    alert("hello there");
    console.log("hello there");
 
}
```

the server is throwing a 406 error but the code still prints the "script tag imbedded" line. in addition, somewhere in the error, I see "404 & source" line in the midst.

Can anyone tell me why shopify won't accept my tag. thank you

Comment: can you post request and response headers ?

Comment: The url for script tags is `/admin/script_tags.json` and you have `/admin/script_tag.json`